# Left rotating array by d elements in C++ using vectors

Tags: c++, arrays, data-structures

The C++ function code I wrote:-

values of n=5(no. of elements in array) and d=4(no. of elements by which array is to left rotated)

```
vector<int> rotateLeft(int d, vector<int> arr) 
{
    int n=arr.size();
    vector<int> temp; 
    for(int i=0;i<d;i++)
    { temp[i]=arr[i]; }

    for(int j=d;j<n;j++)
    { arr[j-d]=arr[j]; }

    for(int k=0;k<d;k++)
    { arr[n-d-k]=temp[k];
    }
    return arr;
}
```

input given `arr[]= 1 2 3 4 5`
output required `arr[]=5 1 2 3 4`

Comment: I'm not sure you've asked a question...?

Comment: Yes. I've asked a question.

Comment: @SakshiMishra: No, I don't think you have.

Comment: Sorry But this is my First question here...I tried to ask it in the best way possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You get `Segmentation fault` for two reasons:

- You have to resize `temp` to match `arr` before accessing the elements with the square brackets either with `std::vector<int> temp(n);` or calling `temp.resize(n)` afterwards.
- You have made an indexing error which results in an access that is out of bounds: `arr[n-d-k]=temp[k]` should actually be `arr[n-d+k]=temp[k]`. In order to avoid this you might try using the `.at(i)` operator instead: It performs an out-of-bound check.

Try it [here](https://wandbox.org/permlink/FH2GnORNMIepZ55a).

---

There is also a function in the standard library for that called [`std::rotate`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/rotate).

```
 std::rotate(arr.begin(), arr.begin() + d, arr.end());
```

Try it [here](https://wandbox.org/permlink/tAOmXbRd5jIE0qY2).

---

If I had to write my own version quickly I would actually do something like

```
template <typename T>
std::vector<T> rotateLeft(std::vector<T> const& vec, int const d) {
  std::size_t const N = vec.size();
  std::vector<T> temp;
  temp.resize(N);
  for (std::size_t i = 0; i < N; ++i) {
    std::size_t const new_i = (N + i - d)%N;
    temp.at(new_i) = vec.at(i);
  }
  return temp;
}
```

Try it [here](https://wandbox.org/permlink/Fp8ZueBonoHUy9PQ).

Comment: but I have to do this by Using the above method  and i am getting the compiler message as Segmentation Fault

Comment: @SakshiMishra Modified my answer

Comment: @SakshiMishra Added my own simpler version if you want to have a look.

Answer (score 1):

```
arr[n-d-k]=temp[k];
```

should have been

```
arr[n-d+k]=temp[k];
```